Force one specific acronym to start in lower case in list of abbreviations
I want all the abbreviations in "Abbreviations" to start with capital letters. However, for one particular abbreviation I need to start with lower case: the "ortho" should be lower case and the "Dichlorobenzene" in upper case (only in the list of abbreviations!). In the main text, both should be lower case.
MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[nomain,toc,acronym,automake,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}

\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
\loadglsentries{myglossaries_mwe}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall 
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations,nonumberlist,nopostdot,style=long]
Test text \gls{GHG} and \gls{oDCB}, end of test text.
\end{document}

Glossaries document "myglossaries_mwe.tex":
\newacronym{GHG}{GHG}{greenhouse gas emissions} 
\newacronym{oDCB}{\textit{o}-DCB}{\textit{ortho}-dichlorobenzene}



Tell LaTeX how to treat the letters, distinguishing between being in the glossary section or not.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  nomain,
  toc,
  acronym,
%  automake,
  nogroupskip
]{glossaries-extra}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 

% \hsize is not known at this point, use \textwidth
% at the right moment
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\textwidth}}

\makeglossaries

\newif\ifinglossary
\NewDocumentCommand{\glossaryuc}{mm}{\ifinglossary#2\else#1\fi}
\AddToHook{env/theglossary/begin}{\inglossarytrue}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}
%\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc}% <-- unneeded?

\newacronym{GHG}
  {GHG}
  {greenhouse gas emissions} 

\newacronym{oDCB}
  {\textit{o}-DCB}
  {\textit{\glossaryuc{o}{o}rtho}-\glossaryuc{d}{D}ichlorobenzene}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall 

\printglossary[
  type=\acronymtype,
  title=Abbreviations,
  nonumberlist,
  nopostdot,
  style=long
]

Test text \gls{GHG} and \gls{oDCB}, end of test text.

\end{document}


If you want to avoid line breaks at the hyphen, when the short version is used, do
\newacronym{oDCB}
  {\textit{o}\mbox{-}DCB}
  {\textit{\glossaryuc{o}{o}rtho}-\glossaryuc{d}{D}ichlorobenzene}


Note that \hsize isn't the correct parameter to use, because it's not set at that point to the eventual value.
Further note: I commented automake because it needs a file you don't show.
